# Can I use Google's email-settings sendas API with oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-email-settings-api

I have a valid oauth2 access_token, that has been authorized with the 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/' scope.  I can successfully use this access_token to make requests against other profile api endpoints.

I'm trying to fetch the list of email addresses the account has been verified to send as.  I'm using https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain}/{user}/sendas as the url, and passing the access token in the access_token param.   I'm getting an authorization error when attempting this.

Is the emailsettings API supposed to be accessible via oauth2?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the email setting API is accessible via OAuth 2.0.  I suspect that you might not be using an admin account to retrieve other user's sendas.  Email Setting API is part of the Admin SDK.  If you are using just a regular user account, you will only be able to retrieve your own sendas info

Comment: Emily, thanks for the reply.  I've since tried on another domain which is a paid "Google apps for business" domain, and it works fine.  I think the problems I was having was because the first domain I tried was a free "Google apps for business" account that I set up a long time ago.  It seems free accounts don't have access to this API, which is very unfortunate.  I was trying to retrieve the sendas info from the user's own account.  If there's a chance that Google would enable this API for free accounts, I'd be happy to talk about my use case.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for paid Google apps for business accounts.  It appears to not work for free Google apps for business accounts setup prior to Dec 2012.  When using a free account, the error message when providing the access_token in the Authorization header is "Domain cannot use API."